# Wordpress: archive multiple post types

Tags: php, html, wordpress, archive

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to archive multiple post types on a page, I have an individual archive for each of the post types working fine, but I also want another page that will archive both of them. I'm still quite new to WP so I'm not at all sure if it's possible but what I'm doing so far isn't working correctly:

```
    <?php query_posts('post_type=type01'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="type01-div" data-value="<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('type01_date_select'));
echo $date->format('dnY');
?>">STUFF HERE</div>
    </a>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


    <?php query_posts('post_type=type02'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="type02-div" data-value="<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('type02_date_select'));
echo $date->format('dnY');
?>">STUFF HERE</div>
    </a>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So all the posts from 'type01' are showing up, but the posts from 'type02' aren't. Is it possible to archive both? In separate loops though as each post type will be wrapped in a different div class.

Comment: I'm not sure.. but try adding a wp_reset_query() after endif; and before your new query_posts. As a side note, check this link out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query
It recommends an alternative to how you're querying for posts.

Comment: FYI, theres a WP specific StackExchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com - though as far as I know these questions are quite welcome here as well (as long as its programming related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your query for the next loop, add this between your loops:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have a similar page like this and used this code to do it:

```
<h2>type01</h2>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'type01' ),
    'order' => 'asc',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</ul>

<h2>type02</h2>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'type02' ),
    'order' => 'asc',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Check out this link for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: ahh that's worked! There was a small problem as I have 2 `<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dnY', get_field('field_name'));
echo $date->format('dnY');
?>` on the page, taking the second one out fixed it, but I need both of them in there as they're referencing different dates?

Comment: Can you post some more of your code, and what PHP version are you using?

Comment: I've edited the post to add in the php date function, my new code is now in your format by the way, I just wanted to show you how the php date tags were being used and why they are possibly not working?

Comment: I've dropped the php into a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UVeNK/ like I say taking the second instance of $date out fixed it, but I need them both as they're referencing different dates from different post types. Is there anyway of having them both there?